# Is it safe to use all 4 cores of your pc to train a machine learning model

Tags: linux, machine-learning, cpu, cpu-usage, processor

I am training a ml model on my ubuntu 16.04 .
I wrote a code that utilizes all 4 cores of my pc.
I doubt if this would lead to some sort of crash
Using htop command on terminal shows me my 100% usage of all 4 cores along with many information including 
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core:0 ........ no listen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly safe. The important processes on your operating system will not starve as they have higher priority.

See the priority (PR) and nice (NI) values on the output of `top` command.

If you want to improve the responsiveness of your computer during the calculation, decrease the priority of calculation process with `nice` command. If your run `nice -19 process`, the process will be the last to get the CPU time.

If you want even more control see `prlimit` (simple) or `cgroups` (complex) commands.